# How to run a shell script in PHP?

Tags: php, shell, triggers

I am trying to trigger the running of a shell script using PHP. Essentially, when a user completes an action on our website programmed in PHP, we want to trigger a shell script which itself calls a Java file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Java class file from PHP script on a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128619/run-java-class-file-from-php-script-on-a-website)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and other [Program execution functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php)

Comment: And you can execute the java file directly without invoking a shell script to invoke the java.  <?php exec('java -Xmx1024m -jar "/home/blahblahblah/mydomain/testjava/Test.jar"'); ?> for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) you can invoke scripts and commands.

Answer (score 0):

use the `exec()` function to execute an external script or function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php