# Running bash script using PHP

Tags: php, apache, bash, web-services, cgi

I am working on little project. Task is get ip or address from input field and then run ping command for that ip and finally print result in the webpage.

I have written code:

```
<FORM ACTION="pingIp.php">
    Enter Host: <INPUT name="host">
    <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Submit">
</FORM>

<div class="results"></div>
```

I don't know how to run ping command and retrieve results on webpage. Can you please give little php code as an example?

Comment: `shell_exec('ping -c 4 google.com')`

Comment: @Daan Where I will write this in php file "pingIp.php"!

Comment: Yes to be more precise: `$response = shell_exec('ping -c 4 '. $_POST['host']); `

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a shell script in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754538/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-php)