# executing a java package using exec in php

Tags: java, php, package, exec

I have a folder `AuthoringTool` in the `wamp\www` directory.

Inside this, I have a package `authoring_tool` which contains two java file and related class file. I can execute the package using

```
java authoring_tool.AuthoringTool
```

But when I try

```
echo exec('java authoring_tool.AuthoringTool');
```

in php, it does not respond.

Comment: Any output/error messages in the web server log files? My guess is that the Web server does not find the java executable. Use an absolute path like `/usr/bin/java` (or whereever your java is located)

Comment: Hi take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128619/run-java-class-file-from-php-script-on-a-website

This should make the job;

Comment: does php have permission to access the package ?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a solution to your problem but maby it would help trying to run the [Java package as an EXE](http://javaexe.en.softonic.com/)