# How to call a java function from a Php file?

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I created a JAR file and i need to call its methods from a Php file. I tried doing it with Php-java bridge but, it works only with sun java 6 which is an abandoned version. Also, i feel that using php-java bridge is not the best way of achieving what i want as it was updated ages ago. Are there any other methods which i can follow to call my java functions from a php file?

Comment: Couple methods: 1. Wrap your JAR in a REST/Soap web service, 2. Use RPC, 3. Use php exec

Answer (score 0):

Execute your java programm from PHP with shell_exec(comand to start your java programm), it will return you the output from your java programm as string. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 0):

See [Run Java class file from PHP script on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128619/run-java-class-file-from-php-script-on-a-website).

In a nutshell: Use PHP's exec() function. It needs to be done very carefully, as described in the referenced issue, but if you do it right, (I've found) it can be a cleaner solution than the bridge method.