# Run a test.java file from a php script

Tags: java, php, .class-file

Is it possible to run  a test.java file from php?Or by compiling to .class file? any help?

```
package com.mkyong.test;

import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class SHAHashingExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        String password = "izwipe1|50.00|fethr123";  // data to be made into checksum

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(password.getBytes());

        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        //convert the byte to hex format method 1
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
         sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        System.out.println("Hex format : " + sb.toString());

        //convert the byte to hex format method 2
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0;i<byteData.length;i++) {
            String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xff & byteData[i]);
            if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append('0');
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
        System.out.println("Hex format : " + hexString.toString());
    }
}
```

this is the code i need to excecute.Also I need to pass an argument to this java file

Comment: You can use php's `exec()` function to run a java file but the server needs to be configured to execute java as well, such as within a Tomcat or Resin environment.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128619/run-java-class-file-from-php-script-on-a-website

Comment: How can I configure my apache server to run java?

Comment: The simplest method would be to just compile and run it with shell commands.

Comment: can shell comments be used without installing tomcat in apache server?

Comment: Yes. Just do `javac x`, `java x`

Comment: this is for compiling right?I want to use this with a php file?I wanna sent some arguments to the java code and recieve a return parameter.But how will I use this java file with a php in the  webserver??