# Running my Java program in my server for my website

Tags: java, html

Hope yall doing well. I had a question regarding if I can run a small JAVA program that I have created to assist my website. I used "jSoup" and "HtmlUnit" for the JAVA program and Now I want to put it on my server and make it executable whenever someone opens the webpage. Is it easily possible? I would appreciate if someone can guide me in the right direction!

Best

Comment: so everytime someone goes to your webpage you want to start a java program? What does the java program do? You might be able to use a php script instead of a java program. Php is not difficult to learn and similar to java.

Comment: Does your Java Code manipulate the code of your website? What is the purpose of your program. Could the same be achieved by using standard servlet or JSP? If yes, it would be much easier to use the standards than doing own stuff.

Comment: @Alexanus yes thats exactly what I want. I didnt want to go through the trouble of recreating something ive already created. But I will looking into it now!

Comment: @mschenk74 Yes it pretty much finds and hot links the appropriate video urls from another sources and embeds it to my page. Now i want to run on my server every time someone clicks the page. I am looking into JSP, hope it works out!

Comment: you can start java programs with php, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128619/run-java-class-file-from-php-script-on-a-website

Comment: thanks alex, but I found using Node.js and Javascript is much better than compiling JAVA code on request. Thanks a lot for your help :) @Alexanus