# Unable to run java file in PHP using PHP Java Bridge

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I am executing a `Java` class in `PHP` using `PHP-Java Bridge` following Official documentation.
I have moved NewFile.jar in lib folder in web apps/WEB-INF folder of tomcat
I am creating a file in java then calling that java class in PHP which will create a file in that particular location.
Unable to create file, I don't know what is happening?

File NewFile.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NewFile {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         File file = new File("E:/myfile");

         if(file.createNewFile())System.out.println("Success!");
         else System.out.println ("Error, file already exists.");
      }
      catch(IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

File: test.php

```
<?php 

require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
echo "Hello";
$data = new java("NewFile");

?>
```

This is what i getting in front-end

[image]

Is their problem in my setup or what can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128619/run-java-class-file-from-php-script-on-a-website) help you?

Comment: What have you tried and didn't work? please add source code of your specific problem

Comment: @akshaypatil if you tried the guide you linked, which is the problem?

Comment: "Official Documentation Didn't help me?" yet absolutely no description from you of what is going wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Java class file from PHP script on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128619/run-java-class-file-from-php-script-on-a-website)

Comment: what's the name that you put in the file  MANIFEST.MF

Comment: from your app it seems you need to follow this part of the documentation http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/desktop-apps.php